# Change transparency, shape and size of a categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot using `ggplot` and trying to set the transparency, size and shape for `geom_point` using a binary variable in my dataset.

For example, if `binary_variable == 1` then set the size to 1, shape = triangle, transparency = 0.2, if `binary_variable == 0` set the size to 0.5 etc.

I have been able to make the colour change as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(variable1 = 1:5,
                 variable2 = 1:5,
                 binary = c(0,0,0,1,1))


ggplot(df, aes(x = variable1, y = variable2, colour = as.factor(binary))) +
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "black"), labels = c("cat1", "cat2")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Please always include a minimal working example of your question, along with usable data. A user with as many questions as you should know the importance of this

Comment: Sure, I will get the dput now

Comment: No need to dput, just make a really simple dataframe. It is much cleaner. Ill will edit the question to show

Comment: Thanks, I will save this for the future when I need help with  `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control shape, colour and aesthetics in the same way using the `scale_X_manual` functions. See the [help page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) for all the different ways these can be controlled.

The key part to make this work though is to make sure that you added the variable you want to control to the `aes` part of the `ggplot` function.

Here is an example:

```
df$binary <-  as.factor(df$binary)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable1, y = variable2, colour = binary, shape = binary, alpha = binary)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 0.5)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! much more flexibility over the plot now. I apreciate it!

Comment: One final point: I am trying to rename the `binary` legend and the `0` and `1` parts. Adding `scale_colour_discrete(name = "Binary_0 / Binary_1")` conflicts with the `colour = binary` in your plot.

Comment: You could use mapvalue to change the parameter name before the plot: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/mapvalues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will take a look into it!